# Which is a better way to handle connection pooling?

Tags: jsf-2, connection-pooling, h2, managed-bean, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to implement connection pooling for a JSF 2.1 application which has a H2 database and Jetty 9 Web server embedded in it. I have two options to implement connection pooling for the h2 database. The options being let Jetty implement connection pooling for me, or I define a application scoped managed bean which creates connection pool. I would like to know which would be a better approach in handling connection pooling?

Connection pooling using Application scoped managed bean:

```
JdbcConnectionPool cp = JdbcConnectionPool.create(
             "jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", "sa");
         for (String sql : args) {
             Connection conn = cp.getConnection();
             conn.createStatement().execute(sql);
             conn.close();
         }
         cp.dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either approach of connection pooling is fine. There are many connection pool implementations (each one with advantages and disadvantages), use whatever you feel like using.

If you have a list of statements to execute, then I wouldn't open a new connection for each statement. Instead, execute all statements with the same connection (and statement):

```
JdbcConnectionPool cp = JdbcConnectionPool.create(
    "jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", "sa");
...
Connection conn = cp.getConnection();
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
for (String sql : args) {
    stat.execute(sql);
}
conn.close();
...
cp.dispose();
```

The connection pool can be started / stopped:

- Outside the web application, as a resource (that's a bit more complicated in my view), for example as described in the article ["Database Connection Pooling with Tomcat"](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/04/19/database-connection-pooling-with-tomcat.html). You will find similar documentation for Jetty.
- Using a [ServletContextListener](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/) (also described in the H2 documentation). In my view, this is a bit simpler. The disadvantage is that the connection pool can not be used by multiple web applications.

Comment: I'm trying to use Jetty side implementation for Connection pooling, I'm stuck with this error.13:51:19.689:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Config error at <New id="myds" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext"><Arg>java:comp/env/jdbc/MyH2DS</Arg><Arg>|???<New class="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource"><Set name="URL">jdbc:h2:/data/test</Set><Set name="User">sa</Set><Set name="Password"/></New>|??</Arg></New> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable constructor

Comment: I'm trying to open the database with pool of connections when the web application starts, and close it when the web application stops. I checked H2 documentation and Jetty but couldn't find how to implement this

Comment: I have added info on how to start / stop the connection pool in a web application.

Comment: In my case my web application serves as library to other existing applications which use this connection pool. As of now I am creating an application scoped bean which creates connection pool on start of application using JdbcConnectionPool.create(),but I have been reading few articles on connection pooling and most of them prefer usage of JNDI data source .I'm wondering if it is okay to use my existing design of application scoped bean or is it better to change the design to accomodate JNDI DS?

Comment: If you use the same connection pool for multiple web applications, then I would probably try to use connection pooling mechanism that is included in the servlet container (Tomcat), which is the JNDI data source. Not because of a technical reason, but just because that's the 'common' way to do it for such cases.